# Citrix XenServer iSCSI shared disk?

Tags: xen, iscsi, citrix, xenserver, dell-equallogic

I am running Citrix XenServer Essentials 5.5, with VMs stored on an EqualLogic iSCSI shelf, using XenServer's StorageLink.  I would like to create a "virtual disk" that can be attached to multiple VMs.  This would be used for a cluster file system like OCFS2 or GFS.  This doesn't seem possible using the XenCenter GUI and I can't find anything online about how to do it.

I realize I could simply expose the iSCSI network to the VM and have the VM initiate its own iSCSI, but that creates a lot of security challenges.  This was pretty easy to do on Oracle VM Server, which is Xen based, so I know it's not a limitation of Xen itself.

Maybe there is an "xe-" command for this?  Thanks for any suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'd need to create the VDI from the command line using the 'xe vdi-create' command and then run 'xe vdi-introduce' with the 'sharable' parameter set to 'yes'. Example commands below.

```
xe vdi-create sr-uuid=469353c2-eb18-7ffe-c754-bc3cce211c07 name-label=myvdi type=user virtual-size=100GiB

xe vdi-introduce uuid=cfac1a2d-ac9f-44f3-a621-2e257875bb5d sr-uuid=0ff1387a-739a-36df-31df-1ccc70f229bc type=user location=cfac1a2d-ac9f-44f3-a621-2e257875bb5d sharable=yes
```

Page 175 for more - http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/5.5.0/1.0/en_gb/reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you tell me what command can I run to get the appropriate UUID for the location= parameter for vdi-introduce?  Thanks!